# Linking to Boost thread library fails

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, multithreading, boost

I have a serious problem with Boost 1.52.0.

In Eclipse, I always get:

```
boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:223: undefined reference to `boost::thread::start_thread()
```

Of course I'm using `lboost_system`, and `lboost_thread`, and `lpthread`, and `lrt`, and etc. in the linker library settings.

I'm cross compiling, everything except this is working fine.

What is causing this? How can I investigate? I'm stuck.

Linker command is:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"libs" -L"/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib" -o "Logics" ./src/Logics_all.o -lpthread -lsqlite3 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lboost_system -lboost_thread
```

If I run:

```
nm libboost_thread.so | grep start_thread
```

I got only:

```
0000b3f0 T _ZN5boost6thread21start_thread_noexceptERKNS_17thread_attributesE
0000b4b0 T _ZN5boost6thread21start_thread_noexceptEv
```

Thank you.

Comment: It should be `boost_system`, not `lboost_system`. It's GCC who needs to be invoked with `-lboost_system` (but again, not `lboost_system`), and that means it will be looking for `libboost_system.so` or `libboost_system.a` in specified library search paths. Show the command line of the actual GCC invocation by Eclipse.

Comment: actual command is: arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -L"libs" -L"/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib" -o "Logics" ./src/Logics_all.o -lpthread -lsqlite3 -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lboost_system -lboost_thread

Comment: Where `boost_thread` is located?

Comment: in the libs folder where -L option points. note, that if I rename libboost_thread.so, it gives another error (lib not found-like)

Comment: Run `nm libboost_thread.so` and see if the `boost::thread::start_thread()` symbol is there.

Comment: please see nm command in the description

Comment: Perhaps you are missing some -dev packages which would provide the missing source and/or libs. What distro are you using? You mention arm-linux in your command line, what hardware platform/architecture are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10, all toolchains had been installed via apt-get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally succeeeds, I downloaded the whole boost library and rebuilt everything.

Now it compiles without any issues.

Thank you for both of you.

Comment: I too had a similar problem. The answer for all problems is to install sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev and then in your IDE Linker use boost_thread. That worked for me.